# Sencha Touch native build for Android

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, cordova-2.0.0

Greetings… Hopefully someone has seen and solved this problem before. I finished my first Sencha Touch app, and everything works well in a browser/development environment.  However, I’ve been stuck for a couple of days on the last mile of the native build process using cordova. I use the AccordionList plugin which defines a PL store & model on demand. After extensive troubleshooting, the problem seems to point to the model definition that extends the src/data/model.js  The error says, ‘cannot read property ‘set’ of undefined (repeated 2 times) and it seems to point to the last line of the code below.

```
// Create static setters and getters for each config option
            for (i = 0; i < staticConfigsLn; i++) {
                key = staticConfigs[i];
                for (j = 0; j < copyMethodsLn; j++) {
                    methodName = configNameCache[key][copyMethods[j]];
```

The app gets stuck on the initial splash screen after native or testing builds. Works fine in pre-build browser mode. I’m using Windows 7 w/XAMPP and PHP/MySQL, Android SDK level 19, Sencha Touch 2.3.1 and Sencha Cmd 4.0.4.84

Any tips, ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to load some stores out of sequence, but it was difficult to see in minifed mode. I was able to overcome this hurdle, but not quite finished yet. Thanks for the help!